# Insert HTML at caret position in contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I would like to add an element inside a contenteditable div at a defined position on button click.
I'm currently able to add content right at the end of the document, not at the position where I left the pointer before clicking the button.

```js
function append_content() {
  $("#myBtn").click(function(e) {
    var getOffset = $("#div_edit").offset();
    var relX = getOffset.left.toString() + "px";
    var relY = getOffset.top.toString() + "px";

    var ii = $('<span class="span-add">Add a link</span>')
      .css({
        top: relX,
        left: relY
      });

    $("#div_edit").append(ii);
  });
}
```

```html
<button class="myBtn" id="myBtn">append content</button>
<div contenteditable="true" class="div_edit" id="div_edit">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

How to append the content at the position where the pointer was before clicking outside of the specified div (`$("#div_edit")`) ?

Comment: Once a button is clicked, this button should know that 'it' was clicked. On the list of parent nodes, pick your desired DIV. Insert into that node whatever you need.

Comment: Makes no sense to add event listeners inside a function `append_content`. That function should eventually do what it says - and that's to append content, not to assign listeners to an button. A better variant would be: `$("#myBtn").on("click", append_content);`

Answer (score 1):

### Using execCommand

You could use `execCommand` with `insertHTML` in order to insert a desired HTML portion at the caret position. There's no need in such case to track the pointer coordinates:

```js
const elInsert = document.querySelector("#myBtn");

elInsert.addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, `<span class="span-add">Add a link</span>`);
});
```

```css
.span-add { color: red; }
```

```html
<button type="button" class="myBtn" id="myBtn">append content</button>
<div contenteditable="true" class="div_edit" id="div_edit">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae, quasi accusantium vitae ut error distinctio in sit minus, esse cum eos quidem corporis maiores dolores voluptate autem numquam vel illum.
</div>
```

Notice that [`execCommand` is considered deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/execCommand), but will work just fine ATM in every decent browser.

### Using Selection and Range

If you don't want to use the handy-but-deprecated execCommand, you can use [Selection and Range](https://javascript.info/selection-range):

```js
const el = (sel, par = document) => par.querySelector(sel);
const elNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);


const elInsert = el("#myBtn");

elInsert.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const range = getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  range.collapse();
  
  const elNewSpan = elNew("span", { className: "span-add", textContent: "Add a link"});
  range.insertNode(elNewSpan);
});
```

```css
.span-add { color: red; }
```

```html
<button type="button" class="myBtn" id="myBtn">append content</button>
<div contenteditable="true" class="div_edit" id="div_edit">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae, quasi accusantium vitae ut error distinctio in sit minus, esse cum eos quidem corporis maiores dolores voluptate autem numquam vel illum.
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Roko. Is there any way not to use `execCommand` ?

Comment: I'm a little confused as to how this code works. How would you add content inside the div with the id `div_edit`? How did you use this id ?

Comment: "*I'm a little confused*" the execCommand runs whereever the cursor is at the time - so it goes in div_edit because that's what you have selected when you clicked the button